# Google Chrome browser warning for goo.gl

Tags: web-browser, malware, chrome

I am getting the solid red screen Chrome browser malware warning for Google's **own** URL shortening website, `goo.gl` as well as other sites such as `bit.ly` and `delicious.com` when I try to navigate there directly via the web (not mobile/tablet device) tonight.

[image: example screen shot for bitly malware]

This seems rather unlikely! What might be the cause?

Comment: I have a same issue, Google Chrome says malware on bit.ly when I try to visit my website

Comment: Because at this time, it is highly probable that shortened links are malicious. Until these link shortening services start scanning their own product and eliminating malware links proactively, the problem will only get worse.

Comment: I wish I had taken the screenshot for goo.gl as that was what really worried me! That is one of two of Google's short URL domains. The other is g.co (I think).

Comment: I think this question is similar to this answered question:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71627/is-bit-ly-a-malware-distributor

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Yes, thank you, for bitly, but why for goo.gl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's Diagnostic page says:
http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl

> Part of this site was listed for suspicious activity 1 time(s) over the past 90 days.

URL-Shorteners are often used to obfuscate malicious links. Google's own link shortener is no exception.

Maybe the safebrowsing blacklist overreacted and just blacklisted everything below goo.gl